# Xcode 65 error while running Appium Inspector

Tags: xcode, webdriver, appium, xcode14

I'm facing this error while running Appium Inspector:

> Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with **code 65 xcodebuild error** message

My versions:
Xcode version - 14.2
Appium version - 1.22.3

Opened **"WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj"** in Xcode and saw this failure:

> ld: cannot link directly with dylib/framework, your binary is not an allowed client of /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCTAutomationSupport.framework/XCTAutomationSupport for architecture arm64

Is this related?

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue and I followed those steps:

1. npm uninstall appium
2. npm install -g appium@next
3. appium plugin install execute-driver
4. appium -pa /wd/hub --use-plugins execute-driver
5. appium driver install xcuitest
6. appium driver install uiautomator2

Took the solution from:
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/17497